# Currency code and value appearing with no space in Form Header

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In Dynamics CRM 2011, I am getting the following problem. I have a Currency field set up, and have displayed it in the Header of the Form as well as in the main body.

In the Header I am getting this, with no space between "USD" and the amount.

[image]

Whereas on the main form I am getting it with a space, as required (not a huge space but at least it's there!):

[image]

Is there any way I can get the space to appear in the Header version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great answer for you I'm afraid, but I believe the answer here is "no". 
The reason that it looks different in the header is that CRM simply uses a different control to display in the header.

I can confirm that this behaviour is repeatable in CRM Online. I wondered if it might be possible to change the "currency symbol" (you can't change the currency code) to "USD " but the trailing space is trimmed whenever the value is saved in the Currency record. If you really need it, you might extend that concept and save your currency symbol as "USD__" perhaps but it's far from elegant.

Of course, you could whip out some JavaScript to attack this but I doubt it's worth the unsupported change for something that is fundamentally just cosmetic.

As a final option, again inelegant, but adding the "Holding Value" onto your form in several more places as a read-only field would make it visually accessible wherever the user is on the form which sort if achieves the same aim as putting it in the header.

Edit: another option might be to introduce a new `float` attribute that is populated by (in order of preference) plug-in, workflow or JavaScript so that it always contains the same value as "Holding Value". You could then place the currency code *and* your new field in the header to approximate the same layout as you see in the form body.

Comment: Hi Greg and thanks for the detailed answer. I had thought about doing JavaScript, although it would be even more complicated than normal because I've found the regular Page APIs can't reach the header. I've mocked up a one-row-one-column web resource in the past that self populates the value required, but that's quite inelegant. I'm interested by the fact that you say the JScript would be unsupported. Which aspect of it is unsupported?

Comment: Simply the fact that, as you imply, there are no methods or functions documented within the CRM SDK that enable changes to the display of values in the header. Consequently you would need to start manipulating the Document Object Model. It is this latter point that makes it unsupported :)

Comment: Ah OK. I just wondered if the fact that I could insert a self contained web resource instead of a field could keep it within the "supported" realm. Actually the field concerned is read only and is never edited by the user, it is populated directly via a Scribe update so my most likely solution may be to keep the currency field hidden in the background and instead populate the currency + space + amount into a regular text field during the Scribe integration phase. I've had to do something like that in other places actually as some forms require displaying values in more than one currency.

Comment: I should be clear - embedding a custom web resource that *looks* like a CRM field *is* supported and would be a viable solution.